# A problem with using dipsw and lcd in AVR

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, proteus

why when I turn on another switch the content doesn`t change?

There is a problem using dipsw and lcd in atmega16 microcontroller.
The problem is not to change lcd content when I turn on another switch.

I compiled my codes using codevision AVR. and my codes are :

```
      a = PINB;

  switch(a){      

    case 1:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 1");
    break;

    case 2:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 2");
    break;

    case 4:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 3");
    break;

    case 8:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 4");
    break;

    case 16:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 5");
    break;

    case 32:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 6");
    break;

    case 64:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 7");
    break;

    case 128:
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_putsf("Switch 8");
    break;

    default:
        lcd_clear();

  }
```

and I made it in proteus :

[image]

when I turn on one of the switches it works fine but when I turn that switch off it continues to show the content and not to clear it, and after that when I turn on another switch the lcd shows nothing.

Comment: Define your problem "There is a  problem" does not define it. Then ask a specific question relating to your problem, thanks

Comment: did you enable the pin pullups on PORTB?

Comment: it doesn`t work at all when the pin pullups are enable on PORTB

Comment: As @PeterBennett said: With your switches connected to positive supply (Vdd), you'd need pull-*down* resistors in place. The AVR does not have pull-downs, only the choice between pull-ups or nothing, so either connect the switches to ground and use the internal pull-ups, or install dedicated pull-down resistors.

Comment: Thank You! My problem solved by installing dedicated pull-down resistors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your software wants one, and only one, bit High to display the "Switch N" message, but your switches pull the inputs Low when "On".

You will need pull-ups enabled on Port B to ensure that the inputs are High when the switches are Off.

Turn all switches On to clear the display, then turn one switch at a time off to get the appropriate "Switch N" message.

**Correction:**
Because you show the common connection of the switches connected to a downwards-pointing arrow, I thought they were grounded - a closer look at the schematic shows the switch common is to the positive supply.  In that case, you require pull-downs on the inputs, not pull-ups, and an "On" switch will pull an input bit High.

Turning all switches Off should clear the display.

Comment: I set pullups/output value on P but it isn`t working at all.

Comment: I suggest that you display the value of "a" in hex, so you can see what the processor is actually reading, and see the value change as you flip the switches..